Colouring multirow and multicolumn table
I have this table in Latex, but the problem is that the colour of the first cell only marks half of it, so half is white. I understand that this has some issue with the rowcolor not working well with multirow, but I haven't figured out how to fix it. How can I make it so that the cell is entirely coloured and not half?
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.5\linewidth}|m{0.2\linewidth}|m{0.2\linewidth}|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering\textbf{Task}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Number of people in}} \\ \cline{2-3}
 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Group A} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Group B} \\ \hline
Task 1 & $\sim$100 & 150 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{List of people.}
\label{tab_experiments}
\end{table}


I tried checking some other posts (Combining multirow and multicolumn, How to use \multirow, How can we create a multi-column multi-row table at the same time?) but they never deal with the colour, which is my problem. I have found one dealing with colour (Table coloring with multirow and multicolumn) but they have an issue that I also encountered - there is a faint lighter line where the original line of the cell would be that I don't know how to remove and I don't want to have in the cell. It looks like this, which was created with Zarko's answer:


I no longer use multirow and multicol since the arrival of the tabularray package, which allows for easier management of this type of table. Here is a solution using tabularray.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}% for \definecolor
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{|m{0.5\linewidth}|m{0.2\linewidth}|m{0.2\linewidth}|}
\hline
\SetCell[r=2]{c,mygray} \textbf{Task} & \SetCell[c=2]{c,mygray} \textbf{Number of people in} \\ \cline{2-3} 
    & \SetCell{mygray} \textbf{Group A} & \SetCell{mygray}\textbf{Group B} \\ \hline
Task 1 & $\sim$100 & 150 \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\caption{List of people.}
\label{tab_experiments}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Or alternatively with code that is more in line with the spirit of the package
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}% for \definecolor
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
colspec={|X[5,l]|X[2,l]|X[2,l]|},
row{1-2}={mygray,cmd=\textbf}
}
\hline
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Task & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Number of people in \\ \cline{2-3} 
    & Group A & Group B \\ \hline
Task 1 & $\sim$100 & 150 \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\caption{List of people.}
\label{tab_experiments}
\end{table}
\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\noindent
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[2,l]X[1,l]X[1,l]}[hvlines]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor = [HTML]{C0C0C0}]{\bfseries}
  \Block[c]{2-1}{Task} & \Block{1-2}{Number of people in} \\
                    & Group A & Group B \\
  Task 1 & $\sim$100 & 150 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{List of people.}
\label{tab_experiments}
\end{table}

\end{document}

You need several compilations (because nicematrix uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

